# Unable to import bootstrap css in typescript file

Tags: typescript, bootstrap-4, import

I am trying to import bootstrap css file from node_modules but it is not importing whereas I am able to import the scss file.

Below import is not working.

```
import bs from "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Below import is working.

```
import bs from "bootstrap/sss/bootstrap.scss";
```

Can anyone please find that what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the import like this `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`